# Using values of command line arguments in a file other than entrypoint.sh

Tags: tomcat, docker, system-properties

I have a file named `setenv.sh` in my tomcat docker container. I use it from my `DOCKERFILE` like this:

```
COPY setenv.sh /tomcat/bin/setenv.sh
```

In this file, I would like to use some command line arguments that can be passed when I start this docker container. For example, If I run this container like this:

```
docker run -d --name somename -e FIRST_ARG=foo SECOND_ARG=bar
```

Then, in my `setenv.sh` I would like to use them like this:

```
export FIRST_ARG = <value of first_arg passed from command line>
export SECOND_ARG = <value of second_arg passed from command line>
```

**Question**

How can I use parameters passed into `docker run` with `-e` flag in `setenv.sh`?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @SergejJevsejev I've made the question clear by explicitly stating it

Comment: thanks, got the point, hope my answer helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access them directly via `$FIRST_ARG`

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# To access first param end etc...
echo "My constant $FIRST_ARG"
echo "My constant $SECOND_ARG"

exec MY_GPOGRAM
```

No need to `export` them again. Environment variables will be available to the program.

If you have special logic in your script to generate new logic, then do something like this:

```
# some logic
NEW_ENV_VARIABLE = "blablabla $FIRST_ARG"

exec NEW_ENV_VARIABLE=$NEW_ENV_VARIABLE MY_PROGRAM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access them the same way you would use any other environment variable. That said, before you try to use them I would make sure they exist and assign a reasonable default if they don't.

```
if [ -z "$ARG_1" ]; then
    export ARG_1=false
fi
```